# What is Neyman-Pearson lemma? Why is this proof of Neyman-Pearson's lemma look so diffcult?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, soft-question, alternative-proof

What is Neyman-Pearson lemma? Why is this proof of Neyman-Pearson's lemma look so diffcult?

I am consider taking a undergraduate course in my college called mathematics of statistics and in the course description, a term comes up and it look so difficult to me.

What is a book that including a proof that is easy to read?

Please including an alternative proof that is easier if you want to! Appreciate in advance.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the reason it _looks_ difficult is that making sense of the notation takes some work.

Comment: What is its prerequisite to read the notation? @MichaelHardy

Comment: Just the usual: integrals, likelihood functions, intersections, probabilities.  But it's in a notation-intensive style, and I'm guessing that's what could give it a superficial appearance of being abstruse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 12 at [this URL](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/45587/18-441Spring-2002/NR/rdonlyres/Mathematics/18-441Statistical-InferenceSpring2002/42BEBDE5-7C30-4C3F-8217-E9BEF04D700E/0/ps8.pdf) gives a proof of the Neyman--Pearson lemma.  Maybe you'll find that more comprehensible.  (Or maybe not?)

At any rate, the lemma says that for testing a point null hypothesis versus a point alternative, the likelihood ratio test is the unique most powerful test at any particular level (i.e. any particular tolerated probability of Type I error).

Answer (score 0):

A more simple expression of the Neyman Pearson lemma is the following

> A region $W$ maximises $$G(W) = \int_{w \in W} g(w) dw$$ subject to the constraints $$F_i(W) = \int_{w \in W} f_i(w) dw = c_i$$ if and only if for some constants $k_i$ we have that $g_i > \sum k_i f_i$ everywhere inside the region and $g_i < \sum k_i f_i$ everywhere outside the region. (And also given that such region exists)

The first occurrence of the lemma in 1933 (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/596850/164061) for some more history on stats.stackexchange) was in terms of a single constraint function $f_1$ and that makes the sufficiency part easy to prove.

Let $W_{\alpha}$ be the region that maximizes the integral. Then for some other region $W_\beta$ then we can consider three regions

- $W_{a}$ points in $W_{a}$ but not in $W_b$
- $W_{ab}$ points in both $W_{a}$ and in $W_b$
- $W_{b}$ points in not in $W_{a}$ but in $W_b$

Then you can split the integral up into parts like $F(W_\alpha) = F(W_{a}) + F(W_{ab})$ and the differences are

$$F(W_{\alpha}) - F(W_\beta) = F(W_{a}) - F(W_{b}) = 0$$

The part where the regions overlap cancel out. The difference $F(W_{\alpha}) - F(W_\beta)$ must be zero because the regions satisfy the same constraint.

$$G(W_{\alpha}) - G(W_\beta) = G(W_{a}) - G(W_{b})$$

where we know that $G(W_{a})>kF(W_{a})$ because it is a region inside $W_\alpha$ and $G(W_{b})<kF(W_{b})$ because it is a region outside $W_\alpha$. Thus

$$G(W_{\alpha}) - G(W_\beta) \geq k F(W_{a}) - k F(W_{b}) = 0$$